# Как ввести ограничение на вводимые данные

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, валидация, grails

Осваиваю Grails, фрейм прикольный, понравилось, что в классе можно вводить валидацию на вводимые данные. Так вот, как мне сделать так, чтобы одно поле в классе в constraints могло содержать латиницу/кириллицу, содержало только цифры и пробел(без : , . и т.д). Через регулярки? Может, есть что-нибудь умнее?

```
 class User
 {
    int id
    String address
    String email
 }

    static constrains 
 {
    address ???
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Да все опять же, через регулярки.

```
static constrains 
{
  address(matches: "[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z0-9 ]")
}
```

И готово...